# Showing a WCloud with cv::viz module

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to show a pointcloud generated by myself with the function reprojectImageto3D() of opencv. The opencv type of this pointcloud is CV_32FC3 and its called 'xyz' in my code.

I have done the next inside of a properly main() with the properly libraries aswell:

......

```
    /// Create a window
        viz::Viz3d myWindow("Viz Demo");

        /// Start event loop
        myWindow.spin();

        /// Event loop is over when pressed q, Q, e, E
        cout << "First event loop is over" << endl;

        /// Access window via its name
        viz::Viz3d sameWindow = viz::getWindowByName("Viz Demo");

        /// Start event loop
        sameWindow.spin();

        /// Event loop is over when pressed q, Q, e, E
        cout << "Second event loop is over" << endl;

        /// Event loop is over when pressed q, Q, e, E
        /// Start event loop once for 1 millisecond
        sameWindow.spinOnce(1, true);
        while(!sameWindow.wasStopped())
        {
            /// Interact with window

            /// Create a cloud widget
            viz::WCloud cw(xyz, viz::Color::red());
            /// Display it in a window
            myWindow.showWidget("CloudWidget1", cw);

            /// Event loop for 1 millisecond
            sameWindow.spinOnce(1, true);
        }

        /// Once more event loop is stopped
        cout << "Last event loop is over" << endl;
```

.......

The problem is that i cant see the pointcloud in the window but there are not compiling erros. I press 'q' to exit the properly loops and wait but nothing appears in the window.

Comment: it's probably 'behind' you.

Comment: @berak i dont understand what u are refering

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

maybe is the format of your Mat, it needs a CV_32FC3 , meaning you need a 3 channel Mat, you should see if the mat that reprojectImageTo3D is of that type or if you have to parse it, or have you already solved this?

Comment: http://sysmagazine.com/posts/217021/ here you can find a little bit more info but it is not perfectly translated

Comment: ok forget what I said... i just tested the reprojectImageTo3D and it does gives you a CV_32FC3 Mat...so if i load a Mat from a PLY it works but not one from a reproject... this is weird o.O if you solved it please tell me how you did it hehe